# Javascript - Get function out of loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I have to following code:

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('Box');

for(i=0; i<box.length; i++){
  box[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  };
}
```

And I am trying to get the function out of the loop like this, but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
//get function out of the loop
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('Box');

for(i=0; i<box.length; i++){
  box[i].onclick = getBlue();
}
function getBlue(){
  this.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

http://codepen.io/AndrewRed/pen/OyBLzw?editors=001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a reference to the function.

```
box[i].onclick = getBlue;
```

If you add parentheses, this calls the function and sets the value of `box[i].onclick` to be the return value of `getBlue` which in this case is `undefined` since it does not return anything.

Comment: Isn't it also best practice to define the affect the function to a variable (i.e. `var getBlue = function() { <code> };` for this kind of use?

Comment: Not unless you specifically want to avoid [function hoisting](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/), otherwise, there's no reason to use an anonymous function, as it [hurts debuggability](http://www.javascriptkata.com/2010/05/19/how-to-de-anonymize-your-anonymous-functions/).

Comment: I kind of think thats personal preference. For me it would depend on where the function was defined for me to make a decision if I need to reference it with a variable. @DanPrince thanks for edit. Suppose I should have given a bit more detail. =]

Answer (score 1):

your calling the function here:

`box[i].onclick = getBlue();`

instead pass `getBlue` as handler;

`box[i].onclick = getBlue;`

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you can replace a variable by its value. So lets replace `getBlue` with the function definition. This should look exactly the same as the first example:

```
box[i].onclick = getBlue();

function getBlue(){
  this.classList.toggle('active');
}

// becomes 

box[i].onclick = function getBlue(){
  this.classList.toggle('active');
}();
```

Oh oh! Nevermind the function name, but this doesn't look like the first example! There are `()` after the function, which don't appear in the first example:

```
box[i].onclick = function(){
  this.classList.toggle('active');
}; // <- no () here
```

Where do they come from? From `getBlue()` of course. What do `()` after a function do? They call the function. It should be clear now that in the first example you don't actually call the function, you simply assign a reference to the function to `onclick`.

Knowing that now, we know how the proper replacement should look like:

```
box[i].onclick = getBlue;
```

without the `()`.